# Need Regex to create an array of id`s

Tags: javascript, html

Hi this is my problem.

```
<div id='whatever'> 
<p id='1'> I am 5 years old  </p> 
<p id='3'> my mum is 40 years old </p> 
<p id='7'> check out this number 7 </p> 
<p id='8'> 78 99 46 </p> 
</div>

elem = document.getElementById("whatever").innerHTML;
target_array = elem.match(/???????????/g);

// => target_array = [1,3,7,8]
```

I didn´t find a Regex which provide me this target_array.
(\d)    (i get to much)
(\d)?=' (didn´t work)

Comment: Your approach is incorrect. Iterate over children of `div`.

Comment: Right, regex is for strings not for iterating dom elements and accessing their properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you're trying to get it using RegExp when you can do it simply by traversing the DOM:

```js
var ids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#whatever > p'))
  .map(item => item.id);

console.log(ids);
```

```html
<div id='whatever'>
  <p id='1'> I am 5 years old </p>
  <p id='3'> my mum is 40 years old </p>
  <p id='7'> check out this number 7 </p>
  <p id='8'> 78 99 46 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it!

```js
  document.getElementById('but').addEventListener('click', function(ev){
   function valid(w) { 
    return w.innerHTML.match(/check/g); 
   }
   var d = document.getElementById('whatever');
   var p = d.querySelectorAll('P');
   var f = Array.from(p)
    .filter(valid)
    .map(item => item.id);

   console.log(f);
  });
```

```html
 <div id='whatever'> 
  <p id='1'> I am 5 years old  </p> 
  <p id='3'> my mum is 40 years old </p> 
  <p id='7'> check out this number 7 </p> 
  <p id='8'> 78 99 46 </p> 
 </div>
 <button id='but'>Test</button>
```